# Generate ADO.NET dataset using an EF context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

There is a project with EF code first classes defined.
Is there a way to generate a dataset with datatables and all relationships using specified EF context on the fly?

Comment: Maybe there is library out there on NuGet or GitHub but  there is nothing built into the framework that would do this. The main reason is that EF was designed to give a more OO approach to dealing with the persistence layer.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  That's exactly the opposite of what EF does (ORM).  Basically you're adding double overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You really just need a `IEnumerable<T>` -> `IDataReader` translator, like this one: [ObjectDataReader](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ObjectDataReader-8476dd72).  Then you can call [DataTable.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_Load_System_Data_IDataReader_) for each Entity Set to load a bunch of DataTables, which you can [DataSet.Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.merge?view=netframework-4.7.2) into a single DataSet.

If you need to create the [DataSet Relations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.relations?view=netframework-4.7.2), that would require extra work.